# YouTube API v3 only displaying 5 results where it should display 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

So, I appear to have hit a problem for which I can't find any relevant information!

Essentially, I have been trying to write this YouTube API call pretty much all day, and when I finally think it is complete I realise that it is only displaying 5 results, and not 7 as it should be doing.

Edit: All 7 do display on the JSON call if I was to visit the $.getJSON('URL') in my browser. The two videos appear to be going missing during the parsing?

The jQuery is as follows:

```
        $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=7&playlistId=UUmaGgGFQU_1cv3X4pIUzW9g&key={API_KEY}',function(data){
        var i = 0;
            $.each(data, function() {

             if (typeof(data.items[0]) != "undefined") {
             console.log('video exists ' + data.items[i].snippet.title);
                title = data.items[i].snippet.title;
                description = data.items[i].snippet.description;
                videoID = data.items[i].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                if ( i <= 0 ) {
                    $('#player').append('<div class="first-videocontainer"><h3>'+title+'</h3><iframe width="1120" height="630" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoID+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
                }
                else {
                    $('#player').append('<div class="videocontainer"><h3>'+title+'</h3><iframe width="365" height="205" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoID+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
                }
                console.log(i);
                i++;
           } else {
                 console.log('video not exists');
                } 
            });      
        });
```

I have set the `maxResults=7`, as I believe this is the only parameter available using APIv3(?).

I'm receiving these errors in the log too, though from Googling them I don't even know if they're of any help because I certainly couldn't find anything constructive from them:

```
GET chrome-extension://fjhoaacokmgbjemoflkofnenfaiekifl/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED

XHR failed loading: GET "chrome-extension://fjhoaacokmgbjemoflkofnenfaiekifl/cast_sender.js".
```

So I'm wondering if it's something simple in the jQuery I've just overlooked, or whether my API call is just terrible. This is the first time I've tried to work with this!

Any help is appreciated.

---

Edit 2: It looks as though it is possibly returning the default value and ignoring my parameter? **However**, if I set `maxResults=4` it does listen.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id

"The maxResults parameter specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set.

Note: This parameter is supported for use in conjunction with the myRating parameter, but it is not supported for use in conjunction with the id parameter. Acceptable values are 1 to 50, inclusive. The default value is 5."

Comment: Make sure that all the videos you are trying to pull in are set to public and embeddable (you have to manually set them in YouTube). If they are not set to public, the API will only pull the videos in the library that are set to public.

Comment: that is probably your answer, did you try many other queries and it always only returns 5 ??

Comment: They are set to public, sadly - I am able to take the embed link YouTube provides and insert them manually. I should also mention that when I visit the URL (https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=7&playlistId={PLAYLIST_ID}&key={API_KEY}) all 7 are displaying as JSON. It is just not displaying them when I make the call and parse it.

Comment: And when you `console.log(data);` at the beginning of callback function before loop. How many objects it returns to browser console?

Comment: If I `console.log(data);` it returns `Object {kind: "youtube#playlistItemListResponse", etag: ""xxxx"", nextPageToken: "CAxQAA", pageInfo: Object, items: Array[7]}`

Comment: The entirety of the information necessary for each video is actually present in the `console.log(data)` too... they're just not displaying on the page it seems.

Comment: what is the playlistID so we can check?

Comment: Current call is using: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=7&playlistId=UUmaGgGFQU_1cv3X4pIUzW9g&key={API_KEY}

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm late in reply but use this url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channelId}&maxResults=50&key={apikey}
```

Happy coading